# Python : How to write a function counting number of word that does not contain a specific letter?

Tags: python-2.7

How to write a function counting number of word (in a list) that does not contain a specific letter? In that case the letter would be E. For example:

```
word_list=['eaa','eaa','eaa','aaa','aaa','aaa']


letter='e'
```

I want to get the result

> 3

And put it in a function `def`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can get the approach and work your way through it as,

1) split the array where `,` occurs.

2) Now when you have those sub-arrays you can iterate and check if `e` occurs,update a counter variable

3)When the loop terminates print the counter

**Time Complexity would be O(n^2)**

Answer (score 0):

An `O(n)` solution would be:

```
len([x for x in word_list if letter in set(x)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to go with filter :

```
word_list=['eaa','eaa','eaa','aaa','aaa','aaa']

print(list(filter(lambda x:'e' not in x,word_list)))
```

output:

```
['aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa']
```

if you want to count then just use:

```
print(len(list(filter(lambda x:'e' not in x,word_list))))
```

output:

```
3
```